# Redirect with POST to application/csv without form

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, redirect

I have a link/button on my page that should lead the user to a csv file.
The csv file is generated dynamically using PHP, based on some POST variables:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=e".date('ymdHis').".csv");
    ...
?>
```

How can I redirect to the script, at the same time passing POST variables, without using a form?

Answers I found that I didn't really like:

- Create a hidden POST form with the desired variables and trigger a post using javascript
- Use jQuery.post to load the page -- I don't yet see how I can use jQuery or AJAX in general to redirect the page

Comment: Also, where do you want the user to go after clicking the link/button?

Comment: There is a form that is used to execute a search. The search script can return JSON or CSV; the problem is that the form is already in use to perform and format the JSON input.

Comment: So my idea was to clone the form (jQuery makes this semi-easy), but I just find it messy to introduce elements to the DOM tree.
What I did in the end is modify the existing form (change action+method), submit it, and change it back. Not beautiful, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use GET method - user won't see GET string (ugly URL), it won't be displayed in the new window. But if you really need POST (though i cannot even imagine why), you should create form with hidden fields - this is the only way to do your task (yes, i've tested many ways before saying this).

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution I've found, but I was skeptical... I need POST because the script only accepts POST.

Comment: Thank you. And you're right, GET wouldn't be bad, with content disposition, the user doesn't see the URL anyway.